# Why "yours truly" means "me"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, politeness, formality

I don't understand how `yours truly` can mean `me`, they are two complete differents words, maybe if it was `mine truly` I could understand a little better, but the `truly` part would stil being strange.
¿Does anyone knows why it's `yours truly`?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166332/how-did-yours-truly-become-a-euphemism-for-i-or-me

Comment: "I remain **yours truly**" ... as in "belonging to you."

Comment: @Robusto, I saw that in a letter for get a job, how that would mean "belonging to you"?

Comment: @EnderLook: That's actually what it means. At this point it's an ancient artifact from a bygone era, but at one time it was considered polite to say that or "I remain your obedient servant" or any of a number of self-abnegating confections, however insincerely felt they may have been.

Comment: @Robusto, but, is it fine write that in a letter for a job applicant?

Comment: "Yours truly" is inappropriate in a business letter because of the intimacy that it implies; try "Sincerely" or "Regards".

Comment: @user159691 Indeed, that seems closely related enough that I'd probably call it a duplicate if the questions were both on the same site. Given that they're not, maybe you could post an answer that references that other question?

Comment: Thank you for having made a good effort to provide relevant tags.  Users with 2,000 reputation can easily change the tags.  Don't worry about not knowing most of the possible tags yet.  As long as you try to provide relevant tags, things will work out.  (You might choose great tags yourself.  Or someone might gladly improve them.)

Comment: @Robusto Did you mean to say "however insincerely they may have felt"? Because the structure your current sentence is essentially: the self-abnegating confections may have been felt insincerely (by people), where insincerely is an adverb modifying people's action (feel).

Comment: @Eddie: Nope. The last clause relates to "confections."

Answer (score 1):

`your truly` doesn't mean {me}

Consider the sentence

> I am yours.

It means that I am declaring that I belong you.

> I am yours truly.

This adds that the statement is true.  Now reverse the sentence.

> Yours truly, I am.

This is not done often and makes the sentence sound more formal.  (This is how Yoda speaks to sound wise.)  Next, drop the "am".

> Yours truly, I.

This is very rare, but is done at times for effect.  From Pink Floyd's "Learning to Fly":

> Tongued tied and twisted just an earth-bound misfit, I.

Now, replace "I" with your name and you have the standard

> Yours truly,
>
> --writer's name--

It does not have the original meaning, though.  It is a figure of speaking roughly meaning "This is the end of the letter and my name is next."

This ending is not as common as it was in the past.  More common today are "Yours", "Best Regards", "Regards" or nothing at all before the name.

Comment: Except it *can* be used to mean *I* or *me*, as you can see from [any](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/yours-truly) [good](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/yours-truly) [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yours_truly).

Answer (score 0):

"Yours truly" is a special expression referring to oneself ("I" or "me") in a humble way.

At the end of a letter, it means something like, "I am sincere to you" or "I am truly yours" (depending on how we interpret "truly," which has a few different meanings).

However, you may also see it used (often facetiously or tongue-in-cheek, but not always) in a sentence like, "Here you go; as promised, the goods scrupulously compiled by yours truly." Here, it just means "me."

Here's a simply laid-out, helpful reference: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yours_truly